# Why is PHP GD Library enabled from CLI but not when being accessed through Apache?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, gd

I'm on a EC2 Amazon AMI 2 with PHP7.2, Apache 2.2 box.

GD library is enabled if I execute a the file from CLI:

```
# php gd.php
```

But it fails from the web:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function imagecreate()...
```

Also, PHP Info from CLI:

```
# php -i|grep gd
/etc/php.d/20-gd.ini,
gd
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning => 1 => 1
```

And PHP info from Web:

[image: Only match for "gd"]
*Only match for "gd".*

Comment: PHP CLI and PHP's Apache mod usually have different php.ini-files and can have different extensions enabled.

Comment: Often there are 2 different `php.ini` file. One for the CLI and one for PHP under the web server. Look at the `phpInfo()` output for `Loaded Configuration File` That is the `php.ini` that is being used by PHP under the web server. Then compare with `php --ini` output

Comment: Noted @MagnusEriksson. Checked that, same php.ini file is being used.

Comment: Noted @RiggsFolly. Checked that, same php.ini file is being used.

Comment: Have you restarted the web server after enabling the extension?

Comment: Well if there is no `GD` section in the `phpinfo()` output it has not loaded the extension for some reason. Have you checked the php error log

Comment: Yes of course @MagnusEriksson.

Comment: Nothing on the logs @RiggsFolly

Comment: Exact same problem here...

Answer (score 0):

First of all open your php.ini and uncomment `extension=gd`
Then restart your server.

Everything will work fine.

This is for xampp running `php 8` on windows